# Merge {sty} and {packages}

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tagging

I just saw that for some reason we have a [sty](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sty) tag with two questions. These questions should be retagged [packages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/packages). However, I think that it is useful to keep [sty](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sty) as a synonym for [packages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/packages). So, if nobody has any objections, I ask a mod to merge the two tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's meaningful, so I merged [packages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/packages) and [sty](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sty), keeping [sty](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sty) as synomyn for the main tag [packages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/packages).